# Google Glass GDK send SMS

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is it possible to send SMS programmatically from Glass?  The use case is sending an auto generated sms message using users phone.  I know this is possible with android sdk, will this work automagically on Glass?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. Glass doesn't have a SIM card and therefore it can't send SMS. You can, however, send the message to a phone (with a SIM card) first. Otherwise, there's services like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) so you don't need a SIM card at all!